# How can save the order of a string?(Python 3.)

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates

I need to save the order of the words in a string, where each word is identified with the (1 based) index of its first occurrence.

For the sample input

```
sentence = "i am what i am am"
```

the desired output is

```
order = "1 2 3 1 2 2"
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: So you assign each word from left to right an incrementing number and if a word has already been in the string, it gets the same number as its first occurrence?

Comment: It would be nice if you had shared a little bit more information about what you have already tried to tackle this problem. In general, your questions will be better received if you show some effort on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary to keep track of where a word has been seen first:

```
s = 'i am what i am am'
seen = {}
result = []
for index, word in enumerate(s.split(), 1):
    result.append(seen.setdefault(word, index))
result = ' '.join(map(str, result))

print(result) # 1 2 3 1 2 2
```

Comment: Faster than me... :/

Comment: or a list comprehension: `result = [seen.setdefault(word, index) for index, word in enumerate(s.split(), 1)]`

Comment: @zondo I'm a little hesitant about list comprehensions with side effects, I feel that line would do too much at once.

Comment: @timgeb: What side-effects?  It appears to be the same thing as your loop.

Comment: @zondo I meant the manipulation of a dictionary inside the list comp.